# java 8: How to convert following code to functional?

Tags: functional-programming, java-8

Instead of using the `for` loop, how do I use the Stream API of Java 8 on array of booleans? How do I use methods such as `forEach`, `reduce` etc.?
I want to get rid of the two variables `totalRelevant` and `retrieved` which I am using to maintain state. 
As in a lambda expression, we can only reference `final` variables from its lexical context.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class IRLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // predefined list of either document is relevant or not
        List<Boolean> documentRelivency = Arrays.asList(true, false, true, true, false);

        System.out.println("Precision\tRecall\tF-Measure");

        // variables for output
        double totalRelevant = 0.0;
        double retrieved = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < documentRelivency.size(); ++i) {
            Boolean isRelevant = documentRelivency.get(i);

            // check if document is relevant
            if (isRelevant) totalRelevant += 1;

            // total number of retrieved documents will be equal to
            // number of document being processed currently, i.e. retrieved = i + 1
            retrieved += 1;

            // storing values using formulas
            double precision = totalRelevant / retrieved;
            double recall = totalRelevant / totalRelevant;
            double fmeasure = (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall);

            // Printing the final calculated values
            System.out.format("%9.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t\n", precision, recall, fmeasure);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert above code to functional code using the Java 8 Stream API and Lambda Expressions? I need to maintain state for two variables as above.

Comment: State what you want to do and have first. It would be easier to help.

Comment: @Tunaki edited. Please have a look.

Comment: I don't see any more explanation in text of what it is you want. It's still unclear.

Comment: To name an example: `recall = totalRelevant / totalRelevant;` it’s obvious that `recall` is always one. So what’s the point of this statement? It doesn’t look like getting more meaning when being placed inside a lambda expression.

Comment: @Holger it's not production code. I am just using formulas. The main problem is transforming code to Functional Style.

Comment: @Tunaki Added comments to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, converting imperative to a functional code will only be an improvement when you manage to get rid of mutable state that causes the processing of one element to depend on the processing of the previous one.

There are workarounds that allow you to incorporate mutable state, but you should first try to find a different representation of your problem that works without. In your example, the processing of each element depends on two values, `totalRelevant` and `retrieved`. The latter is just an ascending number and therefore can be represented as a range, e.g. `IntStream.range(startValue, endValue)`. The second stems from your list of boolean values and is the number of `true` value inside the sublist `(0, retrieved)`(inclusive).

You could recalculate that value without needing the previous value, but reiterating the list in each step could turn out to be expensive. So instead, collect your list into a single `int` number representing a bitset first, i.e. `[true, false, true, true, false]` becomes `0b_10110`. Then, you can get the number of one bits using intrinsic operations:

```
List<Boolean> documentRelivency = Arrays.asList(true, false, true, true, false);
int numBits=documentRelivency.size(), bitset=IntStream.range(0, numBits)
    .map(i -> documentRelivency.get(i)? 1<<(numBits-i-1): 0).reduce(0, (i,j) -> i|j);
System.out.println("Precision\tRecall\tF-Measure");
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numBits)
         .mapToObj(retrieved -> {
             double totalRelevant = Integer.bitCount(bitset&(-1<<(numBits-retrieved)));
             return String.format("%9.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f",
                totalRelevant/retrieved, 1f, 2/(1+retrieved/totalRelevant));
         })
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This way, you have expressed the entire operation in a functional way where the processing of one element does not depend on the previous one. It could even run in parallel, though this would offer no benefit here.

If the list size exceeds 32, you have to resort to `long`, or `java.util.BitSet` for more than 64.

But the whole operation is more an example of how to change the thinking from “this is a number I increment in each iteration” to “I’m processing a continuous range of values” and from “this is a number I increment when the element is `true`” to “this is the count of `true` values in a range of this list”.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you need to change your code to lambdas. Currently it's quite short and lambdas will not make it shorter or cleaner. However if you really want, you may encapsulate your shared state in the separate object:

```
static class Stats {
    private int totalRelevant, retrieved;

    public void add(boolean relevant) {
        if(relevant)
            totalRelevant++;
        retrieved++;
    }

    public double getPrecision() {
        return ((double)totalRelevant) / retrieved;
    }

    public double getRecall() {
        return 1.0; // ??? was totalRelevant/totalRelevant in original code
    }

    public double getFMeasure() {
        double precision = getPrecision();
        double recall = getRecall();
        return (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall);
    }
}
```

And use with lambda like this:

```
Stats stats = new Stats();
documentRelivency.forEach(relevant -> {
    stats.add(relevant);
    System.out.format("%9.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\t\n", stats.getPrecision(),
            stats.getRecall(), stats.getFMeasure());
});
```

Lambda is here, but not Stream API. Seems that involving Stream API for such problem is not very good idea as you need to output the intermediate states of mutable container which should be mutated strictly in given order. Well, if you desperately need Stream API, replace `.forEach` with `.stream().forEachOrdered`.

Comment: isn't using Functional Programming style makes code more readable, maintainable? So, Shouldn't we always use it?

Comment: @MajeedSiddiqui Do you honestly find the above code more readable than the for loop? It's simply a different way of writing code that may or may not be appropriate for certain tasks.

Comment: @MajeedSiddiqui, there's no programming concept which we should always use. Like you cannot repair everything having only a hammer. You should use the most suitable tool for every problem.

Comment: @TagirValeev Okay. So, if I am working on some project, is it okay to use combination of Functional as well as Imperative style of programming?

Comment: `fmeasure = 2/(1+retrieved/totalRelevant)`…

Comment: @Majeed Siddiqui: of course, you can mix functional and imperative programming. You may even mix both with object oriented programming…